# Why might different computers calculate different arithmetic results in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, floating-point, math

I have some software written in VB.NET that performs a lot of calculations, mostly extracting jpegs to bitmaps and computing calculations on the pixels like convolutions and matrix multiplication.  Different computers are giving me different results despite having identical inputs.  What might be the reason?

**Edit**: I can't provide the algorithm because it's proprietary but I can provide all the relevant operations:

- ULong \ ULong (Turuncating division)
- Bitmap.Load("filename.bmp') (Load a bitmap into memory)
- Bitmap.GetPixel(Integer, Integer)  (Get a pixel's brightness)
- Double + Double
- Double * Double
- Math.Sqrt(Double)
- Math.PI
- Math.Cos(Double)
- ULong - ULong
- ULong * ULong
- ULong << ULong
- List.OrderBy(Of Double)(Func)

Hmm...  Is it possible that OrderBy is using a non-stable QuickSort and that QuickSort is using a random pivot?  **Edit**: Just tested, nope.  The sort is stable.

Comment: Is it possible to give some simple examples? There may be a pattern in them that someone can recognize, but without a sample, it's much more speculation.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to find the first point at which the calculations start to differ.  That might allow you to narrow the problem down to a single primitive operation that's producing different results with the same inputs.

Are there notable differences between the different machines?  Are they both running the same OS?  Are they both 32-bit (or both 64-bit)?

How different are the results you're getting?  Tiny differences in floating-point values, or something more significant than that?

Do you ever get different sets of results on a single machine?

Comment: I'm not in control of the computers providing different results.  I don't even know which computers they are.  Just users connecting to my server and providing and inconsistent result of a complicated equation.

Comment: Hmm.  That's tricky.  I wanted to suggest floating-point differences (especially between older x86 hardware and newer 64-bit systems) as a possible source:  e.g., it's possible that Math.Cos could be using slightly different algorithms, or working internally in different precisions, on different systems, leading to a tiny difference in numerical results.  Depending on the algorithm, it wouldn't be hard for these tiny differences to be magnified into larger ones.  But it's difficult to do more than guess.

Comment: I got some results from users.  I'm converting loading jpeg iamges as bitmaps and some of the pixels are a little off in color.  Maybe there are different versions of .Net using different jpeg->bitmap conversions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that Bitmap.Load("filename.jpeg") doesn't always produce the same bitmap on each computer.  I still don't know why that is, however.

Comment: I am a little confused. What do you mean dosnt produce the same bitmap (sorry, im a noob and i am creating my own image manipulation library).

Comment: The output of (new Bitmap("foo.jpg")).getPixel(10,10) might be different on each computer.

Answer (score 1):

- one or more bugs in the software (e.g uninitialised variables) ?
- old Intel CPU floating point division bug ?
- numerically unstable algorithm ?

Comment: VB.Net shouldn't have uninitialized variables but I have all warnings turned on for those cases and there are none.  Maybe List.OrderBy() is using a non-stable QuickSort with random pivot?

Answer (score 1):

Screen Drivers - Each Driver will GUI the values differently. While the pixel count is same the color depth may differ via the screen drivers. Now setup into an array and compare that array on those machines you may see a difference of several bytes.

I would print$ the totals and see what they add up to